# How to count await method execution time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a dot net core project. In which I have to count how much had taken by my await method while executing.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<bool> InsertIntoDatabase([Frombody] StudentModel objStu) {
//For Each method and other stuff
  await DoInsert(Fiels Details);
}
```

I am calling this method in Ajax. So after successful execution of code, I want to return the number of times in minutes taken by the method.

This insertion process contains 500+ records.  So, I am interested to calculate the time

Comment: For a bigger analysis over multiple calls use a profiler. I personally like dotTrace but there are other free alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use `Stopwatch`

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<bool> InsertIntoDatabase([Frombody] StudentModel student) 
{
    var clock = new Stopwatch();
    clock.Start();

    await DoInsert(student);

    clock.Stop();
    var minutes = clock.Elapsed.TotalMinutes();
}
```

[Stopwatch Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

Why not return a custom object in your task with the time and the result?

```
private async Task<MyClass> GetResult()
{}

public class MyClass
{
    public bool  Success { get; set; }
    public long TimeInSeconds { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend checking out [MiniProfiler](https://miniprofiler.com/).
It's extremely easy to setup!

1. Install MiniProfiler via Nuget
2. Add the MiniProfiler tag helper to your _Layout.cshtml
3. Add the MiniProfiler tag (`<mini-profiler />`) to your HTML (I put mine in Layout.cshtml as well)
4. Add to services in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMiniProfiler(options =>
{
    options.RouteBasePath = "/profiler";
    options.SqlFormatter = new SqlServerFormatter();
});
```

5. Add this **AFTER** calling `app.UseStaticFiles()`:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
     app.UseMiniProfiler();
}
```

Now MiniProfiler is ready to go and will only appear in development (step 5). To profile some code do:

```
using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("This Will be the label displayed on the front end"))
{
    //code you want to profile
}
```

Now run your code and voila! MiniProfiler will put a very small table on your page (I THINK it defaults top left). Each row is the elapsed of the request (works with AJAX too!).